# What's the best way to direct user to different views by roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, we have a bunch of user roles, such as Admin, ReportUser, ProjectManager and stuffs like these. I want the application to redirect the user to views immediately after login according to the following rules:

If user is Admin, redirect to /Admin/Index

If user is ReportUser, redirect to /Report/Index

If user is ProjectManager, redirect to /Project/Index

I've already set up a role manager using AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider in web.config, and I am setting user roles in MyMvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest of global.asax, which works well.

But, I am not clear where and what is the best way to do the redirect. In OnAuthorization method of a custom authorize attribute class?  Or in MyMvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest method of global.asax?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds very bad what you are doing.  There is no reason to use any HttpApplication events.  Hooking into these really sounds like you are doing some very non-standard authentication/authorization coding.

Comment: My web app will live in an hosting environment which has web agent that supervises all web applications in that environment and does all the authentications. In other words, mine is like a child app. The web agent passes the user authentication information to my app, which in turn merely does authorization based on the user role information that's passed to my app.  So, yes, not a standalone app with its own login logout, but there is nothing I can do about this.

Comment: Eeeewww.  That is really *really* **really** bad design.  I could easily spoof my own credentials as an Administrator.

Comment: Understandable, but there is nothing I can do about it. Customer's been using this design for years.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default Asp.net Identity Login and template logic you should have a login method that looks something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

So create a new method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GoHome()
{
  if (this.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
    return Redirect("Action", "Controller");
  }
  // etc etc
}
```

Then just update the Login method by changing:

```
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

to

```
return Redirect("GoHome");
```

The reason for the double redirect is that authentication takes place before the MVC pipeline, which means that `await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe)` will not change the current user context, it requires a redirect for MVC to see the change.  Thus on the next page, it can read the roles and redirect correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up implementing a custom filter and overriding OnActionExcuting method to redirect the user based on the user's role(s).

Comment: Just so you know, that may not always work.  ActionFilterAttributes are executed after AuthorizationAttributes.  You may want to consider implementing it as an AuthroizationAttribute.

Comment: That's good to know, so far it works nicely. But I will keep that in mind. Thanks.